# How to get which div/ui.helper clicked in drag event jqueryui/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

On Jquery UI's site:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/

If I have:

```
<div id="someId" class="someClass">he</div>
<div id="otherId" class="otherClass">he2</div>
```

And:

```
$('#someid','#otherid').draggable({
    drag: function(event, ui) {
      alert(ui.helper.THEIDOFTHECLICKEDITEM); // What goes here?
    }
});
```

How do I get the id or class of the ID using the "ui" variable from the callback? If not possible, how do I get it from the "event" variable?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want:

```
$("#someId, #otherId").draggable({
    drag: function(event, ui) {
        console.log(ui.helper[0].id);
    }
});
```

(or use `ui.helper.attr("id")`)

**Note**: `ui.helper` is a jQuery object, which is why we must either use `.attr("...")` to retrieve the `id` or access the matched element at index 0 and directly get the id.

---

Or without using the `ui` argument (probably what I'd recommend):

```
$("#someId, #otherId").draggable({
    drag: function(event, ui) {
        console.log(this.id); // "this" is the DOM element being dragged.
    }
});
```

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/LkcSx/